# Python Django Lambda Expressions For Lists

Tags: python

I need to Update a List in Python which is:

```
data = [{' Customers ','null,blank '},{' CustomersName ','max=50,null,blank '},{' CustomersAddress ','max=150,blank '},{' CustomersActive ','Active '}]
```

I wanted to Write a Lambda Expression to Store the Customers, CustomersName in the List and Remove the White Spaces.
I am absolutely New to Python and Does not Have Any Knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, You have Declared the Dictionary Inside a List but the Dict is Wrong, It should be {"key":"value"}, So I assume you need to Change it to List as such:

```
  data = [[' Customers ','null,blank '],[' CustomersName ','max=50,null,blank '],[' CustomersAddress ','max=150,blank '],[' CustomersActive ','Active ']]
```

And Then The Following would get you Your Desired!

```
data_NameExtracted = [x[0].strip() for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put this inside a lambda expression, but you can use a generator object like this:

```
# please note that i have used tuples instead of sets, 
# because sets are unordered
data = [
    (' Customers ','null,blank '),
    (' CustomersName ','max=50,null,blank '), 
    (' CustomersAddress ','max=150,blank '),
    (' CustomersActive ','Active ')
]

# Indexing is not allowed for set objects
values = [item[0].strip() for item in data]
```

see:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

EDIT:

If you wan't to use dictionaries you could use something like this:

```
data = [
    {' Customers ': 'null,blank '},
    {' CustomersName ': 'max=50,null,blank '}, 
    {' CustomersAddress ': 'max=150,blank '},
    {' CustomersActive ': 'Active '}
]
# expecting a single value in the dicts
values = [item.values()[0].strip() for item in data]
```